# How to add custom classes to figure element only if image has caption?

Tags: images, filters, hooks, captions

I want to add the 'wp-caption' class to the figure element only if the image has caption. How do I do that? I'm using the new gutenberg enviroment, if that affects anything.

for example:

form this:

```
<figure class="alignleft"> <img src="#" alt="#"/> <figcaption>Test</figcaption> </figure>
```

to this:

```
<figure class="alignleft wp-caption"> <img src="#" alt="#"/> <figcaption>Test</figcaption> </figure>
```

so the **wp-caption** class was added to figure, because the image has caption.

Thank You